# cURL doesn't work in CRON

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cron

My shell script works fine when running it from terminal (e.g., ./postdata.sh), but when run from CRON it doesn't work.  I've confirmed the PATH and am using full paths to call the shell scripts.  I've also tried several approaches for the cURL command with no changes.

The shell script (postdata.sh) pulls a decimal value from an OWFS file and posts the data to a Google Script that receives the URL encoded values and puts it into a Google Spreadsheet.  I've looked into other approaches to post data to a Google Spreadsheet, but think this is the easiest; if the cron job would work.

```
root@onewire:/home/1wire_admin# cat postdata.sh
#!/bin/bash

urladdress="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyBKdbVyVH2LlMQptNlMiF2KkRn/exec"
reeftemp=$(cat /home/1wire/1F.58D803000000/aux/28.C4C229070000/temperature)

if [ -n $reeftemp ]; then
  # remove whitespace
  reeftemp="$(echo -e "${reeftemp}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')"

  postdata="temp=$reeftemp"

  urladdress2=$urladdress"?"$postdata
  echo "url2 = $urladdress2"

  # Example URL=https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyBKdbVyVH2LlMQptNlMiF2KkRn/exec?temp=98.3

  curl -G -L "$urladdress2"
fi

root@onewire:/home/1wire_admin#
```

---

Crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/

*/5 * * * * /home/1wire_admin/get1wire.sh 1 >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /home/1wire_admin/postdata.sh
```

Comment: What's the error message you get? "does not work" is too vague..

Comment: usually better to redirect cron output like `> /tmp/get1wire.log.`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M 2>&1`. (for both scripts). How are you generating temp info, I'm  interested in this sort of project too. Good luck.

Comment: Check your email. The stderr and stdout will be emailed by cron to the owner of the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how that fix it...but, it's working.  Could it simply be having a place to dump the stdout since I'm using cURL to GET something?

I did not change anything in postdata.sh

*I know that Google Scripts does a redirect which is indicated by the "loading" window that is returned rather than the redirected page that shows the post data in the webpage rather that the "loading" page which is is waiting for the redirect page to be served up.*

Here's what I changed crontabs to

```
*/5 * * * * /home/1wire_admin/postdata.sh >/home/1wire_admin/postdata.out 2>&1
```

Output:(postdata.out)

```
url2 = https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyBKdbVyVH2LlMQpz9LaFos/exec?temp=79.5875


% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100  2805    0  2805    0     0   1542      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  1578
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en">
<style type="text/css">
html,body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}.loading-text {background: url(gwt/images/spin-wait.gif) no-repeat; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; margin: 16px 0 16px 40px; padding-left: 22px;}.loading-box {background-color: white; border: 1px solid #ACACAC; border-bottom-color: #999; box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); margin-top: -25px; margin-left: -100px; padding: auto; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 200px; height: 50px; z-index: 16777272;}.loading-glass-panel {-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30 ); filter: alpha(opacity = 30); opacity: 0.3; background-color: #999; display: block; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 16777271;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var startTime = new Date().getTime(); var tzPointsJson = "[1109635200000,1128902400000,1130657000000,1143333000000,1143806400000,1145000000000,1146380000000,1152489600000,1159800000000,1159500000000,1162095000000,1162075000000,1162105500000]"; var libId = "M6-SQ4FDCwGJ10HMl1cAg2dMtQJv3mDbG"; var payload = "{\x22types\x22:{\x22u892486473779\x22:\x22Label\x22,\x22u892486473778\x22:\x22VerticalPanel\x22},\x22libId\x22:\x22M6-SQ4FDCwGJ10HMl1cAg2dMtQJv3mDbG\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473777\x22,\x22title\x22:\x22\x22,\x22commands\x22:[{\x22args\x22:[],\x22cmd\x22:\x22VERTICALPANEL\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473778\x22},{\x22args\x22:[\x22temp 79.5875\x22],\x22cmd\x22:\x22LABEL2\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473779\x22},{\x22args\x22:[{\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473779\x22}],\x22cmd\x22:\x22ADD\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473778\x22},{\x22args\x22:[{\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473778\x22}],\x22cmd\x22:\x22ADD\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22u892486473777\x22}],\x22sMode\x22:false}"; var _tok = ""; var serviceId = "AKfycbyBKdbVyVH2LlMQptNlMiF2KkRnfaQmjz9LaFos-u-K3VG1h1Bi"; var _sd = true; var _aurg = false; var _ea = false; var _up = '\/macros\/s\/AKfycbyBKdbVyVH2LlMQptNlMiF2KkRnfaQmjz9LaFos-u-K3VG1h1Bi'; var standardsMode = false; var _atok = "";var _MF={0:true,5:true,8:30000,10:"https://console.developers.google.com",12:"https://script.google.com/macros/srvStatic/rpc_relay.html",13:"https://docs.google.com/picker",14:"jeffrey.engelbrecht@gmail.com",15:"https://script.google.com/macros"};
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src=
'gwt/googleappsscripts_userapp.nocache.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.google.com/jsapi'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls', 'annotatedtimeline']});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="loading-glass-panel" id="loading-glass-panel"></div>
<div class="loading-box" id="loading-box">
<div class="loading-text" id="loading-text">Loading...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```